# pointer to preallocated memory as an input parameter and have the function fill it

Tags: c++

Test code:

```
void modify_it(char * mystuff)
{
   //last element is null i presume for c style strings here.
   char test[7] = "123456";

   //when i do this i thought i should be able to gain access to this
   //bit of memory when the function is destroyed but that does not
   //seem to be the case.
   //static char test[] = "123123";

   //this is also creating memory on stack and not the heap i reckon
   //and gets destroyed once the function is done with.
   //char * test = new char[7];

   //this does the job as long as memory for mystuff has been
   //allocated outside the function.
   strcpy_s(mystuff,7,test); 

   //this does not work. I know with c style strings you can't just do
   //string assignments they have to be actually copied. in this case
   //I was using this in conjunction with static char test thinking
   //by having it as static the memory would not get destroyed and i can
   //then simply point mystuff to test and be done with it. i would later
   //have address the memory cleanup in the main function.
   //but anyway this never worked.
   mystuff = test;
}

int main(void)
{
  //allocate memory on heap where the pointer will point 
  char * mystuff = new char [7];
  modify_it(mystuff);
  std::string test_case(mystuff);

  //this is the only way i know how to use cout by making it into a c++ string.
  std::cout<<test_case.c_str();

  delete [] mystuff;
  return 0;
}
```

1. In the case of a static array in the function why would it not work?
2. In the case when I allocated memory using new in the function does it get created on the stack or heap?
3. In the case when I have a string which needs to be copied into a `char *` form. everything I see usually requires `const char*` instead of just `char*`.

I know I could use a reference to take care of this easily. Or `char **` to send in the pointer and do it that way. But I just wanted to know if I could do it with just `char *`. Anyway your thoughts and comments plus any examples would be very helpful.

Comment: If you need to modify a parameter, you need to pass a pointer or a reference to the thing you want to modify. No exceptions.

Comment: Your questions are still unclear.  1) what is "it not work"?  2) Allocating memory using "new" uses the heap.  3) const char\* is a non-mutable version of char\*.  You can copy my_string.c_str() onto a char*.

When you deallocate an array use "delete [] mystuff;".

Comment: Do you need to use C-style strings?  You've tagged the question as C++, not C.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> char * mystuff = new char [7];
> delete mystuff;
> ```

`delete mystuff` is causing undefined behavior. You must `delete[]` what you `new[]`.

Comment: sorry that was a typo. thanks for pointing it out. corrected it

Answer (score 2):

The line `mystuff = test;` causes the variable `mystuff` to contain the address of the `test` array. However, this assignment is *local to the function*. The caller never sees the modified value of `mystuff`. This is generally true for C/C++: function parameters are passed by value, and local modifications to that value are invisible outside of the function. The only exception to this is if you use the `&` operator in the parameter list in C++, which causes the parameter to be passed by reference. Like so:

```
void modify_it(char* &str) { /* ... */ }
```

However, if you do this, your program still won't work correctly, and will probably crash. That's because the address of `test` is stack memory, and that memory will be overwritten when `modify_it` returns. You'll be giving the caller the address of invalid stack memory, which can only lead to bad things. The correct thing to do is one of the following:

```
/* function allocates, caller frees */
void modify_it(char* &str) {
    str = new char[7]; // allocate enough memory for string
    memcpy(str, 7, test);
}
```

Or this:

```
/* caller allocates and frees */
void modify_it(char* str, size_t str_len) {
    if (str_len < 7) { /* report an error. caller didn't allocate enough space. */ }
    memcpy(str, 7, test);
}
```